# Execute a perl script which doesnt have the .pl extension from another perl script which have the .pl extension

Tags: perl

How to execute a perl script with a file named "first" (no extension) from another perl script called second.pl on Windows?

File contents of first:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl5.8.4 -w
>> Some code
```

File contents of second.pl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

system "first";
```

So my problem is when I execute the file "first" from the Windows command line, it works

but if I try to run it from my file "second.pl", using `system "first";`
it fails with the below error:

```
can't exec "first" : Not a directory at "second.pl" at line 6
```

Comment: What about `system 'open first'`?

Comment: Or maybe `system '/path/to/perl /path/to/first'`

Answer (score 1):

Windows uses the file extension to work out how to run a file. As you have no extension the OS is thinking you are trying to open a directory.

You can fix this by changing `system "first";` to

```
system $^X, "first"
```

This will get Windows to run the current Perl interpreter again, passing your script name as the first parameter, which gets Perl to run it.

Comment: Defensive programming advice: it's easy to end up with several installed Perls, sometimes without one's knowledge, and `system "perl"` might not run the one you expect to. Either use [`$^X`](http://p3rl.org/var#$^X) (same Perl as running currently) or hard-code the full path.